# Compare Gameobjects in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I'm an artist, doomed to write C# code for my college :D and I would love to get a helping hand here :)

Problem: I have a small terrain with two objects on it (placed via drag and drop ingame) and I have my loop here which has to check if ObjectA has the same value(s) as ObjectB. So how could I do this? I tried with foreach loop but the condition is true if one of them has the right value, not both of them.

---

For now, the field or small terrain is checking everything.

It checks if it has water, if true -> continue, else return,

if it has two objects, if true -> continue, else return

and if the two objects have same value(s) else return, if everything is true, than place object ...and I'm stuck at the last part -> comparing the two objects.

Each Object has a value, an integer, there are for different objects... object one has value 0, object 2 value 1 etc... but the player should only combine object - value 0 with object - value 0. Which means, if I drag object - value 0 and object - value 1 onto the field, nothing happens, only if I drag object - value 2 and object value - 2 onto the field or object - value 3 and object value - 3.....

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Plantgrowing : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] LayerMask layer, layer2;
    [SerializeField] GameObject plantPref;
    GameObject plant;
    bool compatible = false;
    float waterlvl;
    private void Update()
    {
        Collider2D[] hitInfo = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, .5f, layer);
        Collider2D[] hitInfo2 = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, .5f, layer2);

        foreach(Collider2D hit in hitInfo)
        {
            if (hit && hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Field"))
            {
                waterlvl = hit.gameObject.GetComponent<Fields>().waterLevel;
            }
        }

        if (hitInfo2.Length == 2)
        {
            foreach (Collider2D hit2 in hitInfo2)
            {
                if (hit2.gameObject.GetComponent<Crop>().cropID == 1) //cropID is only a script with one single variable
                {
                    compatible = true;
                }
                else return;

                if (waterlvl >= 5 && compatible)
                {
                    if (!plant) plant = Instantiate(plantPref, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -2), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    Destroy(hit2.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, .5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you spawn the plant only if the conditions are true: the field has water, the two objects are on the field and the two objects have the same value (but which value)?

Comment: it's an integer, there are for different objects... object one has value 0, object 2 value 1 etc... but the player should only combine object - value 0 with object - value 0. Which means, if I drag object - value 0 and object - value 1 onto the field, nothing happens, only if I drag object - value 2 and object value - 2 onto the field.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two objects at most (and you specifically check for that) you can skip the foreach loop and address them directly by their indices

```
if (hitInfo2.Length == 2)
{
    if (hitInfo2[0].gameObject.GetComponent<Crop>().cropID == hitInfo2[1].gameObject.GetComponent<Crop>().cropID)
    {
       //they match
    }
}
```

Complexity of the problem increases if you want to have longer lists and you want to compare all of the elements. There are many solutions (and it all depends on the problem), but in your case this would suffice:

```
int crop = -1;
bool compatible = true;

foreach (Collider2D collider in hitInfo2)
{
    int candidate = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Crop>().cropID;
    if (crop == -1)
        crop = candidate; //initialize 'crop' variable if this is the first object
    else
        compatible = crop == candidate //check if current object is the same as initial

    if (!compatible) break; //stop looping if we found an incompatible object
}

if (compatible)
    ...    //compatible now stores true/false depending on the result
```